# Putting a 'terminal' in my application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Are there any frameworks for say, putting a display like in Terminal.app in MY app, and then displaying text on it like usual output to STDOUT? Complete with scrollback and etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This thread](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2004/Jun/msg01454.html) has a couple suggestions.  The first is very UNIX'y - you use pipe() to map stdout to a new location.  Then you'd need another process or a thread that reads that pipe and displays it into an NSTextView.  The other approach that I liked as it seems cleaner and less resource intensive is to replace the File_writer_t _write proc in the stdout() FILE pointer with the hook that you want, which write the output into an NSTextView.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look at [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/index.shtml), an open-source terminal emulator written in Cocoa. If you really want terminal emulation, you might be able to lift from that framework.